# Flutter Drawer in front of bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, drawer, bottom-navigation-bar

I have a Scaffold widget in my flutter App with a bottom navigation bar.
I created a drawer widget in one page of the app. The drawer is not in the scaffold widget because I don't want to be able to open the drawer anywhere in the app, only in a specific page.
The problem is when I open the drawer, it is behind the navbar.
Any idea how to make the drawer in front of the navbar ?

Here is my code :

Scaffold widget with navbar :

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'App',
  home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: white,
    body: SafeArea(child: HomePage()),
    bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBarWidget(
      navigationBarItemList: [
        NavigationBarItemType(
            'navigationBarItem_one', 'Tab1', CustomIcons.bookmark),
        NavigationBarItemType(
            'navigationBarItem_two', 'Tab2', CustomIcons.calendar),
        NavigationBarItemType(
            'navigationBarItem_three', 'Tab3', CustomIcons.shoppingCart),
      ],
      navigationBarItemSelected: navigationBarItemSelected,
      notifyParent: (value) {
        setState(() {
          navigationBarItemSelected = value;
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Page with drawer widget :

```
return Stack(children: [
  Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      // Content page here
    ],
  ),
  DrawerController(
    key: _drawerKey,
    alignment: DrawerAlignment.end,
    enableOpenDragGesture: true,
    scrimColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
    child: getDrawer(),
  ),
]);
```

Comment: Check this answer [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234225/how-to-make-flutter-drawer-above-bottom-navigation) It might be your answer